# ion_auth with codeigniter redirection issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

I'm using codeigniter 3 and ion_auth for authentication.

I'm trying to get a method in my controller to redirect to another method if not logged in, other than the auth/login page, but whatever i try, it still redirects to the auth/login page???

So for testing purposes, with this method, im trying to get it to redirect to a different method in the same controller 'new_index', but it still redirects to auth/login.

Why is this?

```
public function index() {
    // redirect if not logged in
    if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in()) {
        // redirect them to the login page
        redirect('new_index');
    }
    else {
        $view_data = array(
            'page_title'    => 'Training Dashboard'
        );
        $this->load->view('training/training_dashboard',$view_data);
    }
}

public function new_index(){
    echo "Hello";
}
```

I don't get where the instruction to redirect to auth/login is coming from?

Comment: post your whole auth controller's code.

Answer (score 0):

Did you configured your Base Url in config .If not please set it pointing to project directory